# Finding eigenfunctions for Sturm-Liouville problems.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Many PDE textbooks contain theoretical results regarding existence of eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for Sturm-Liouville problems but I haven't seen any that actually tell how to compute either making the theory seem not very useful. I was wondering how is can you find the eigenfunctions?

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here][1][you can check simple worked out example of Sturm-Liouville problems in the given pdf link also find how to find eigenvalue and eigenfuction of corresponding Sturm-Liouville problems] http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~siva/ma41707/ode7.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I understand that example but it's simple in so far as I don't think SL theory is added for it and the eigenvectors are found using the guess method.

Comment: I meant to write I don't think SL theory is needed* for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SLEIGN$2$ (Sturm-Liouville EIGeNvalue EIGeNfunction) FORTRAN library at
http://www.math.niu.edu/SL2/ .
This was written by experts in the field: Paul Bailey, Norrie Everitt and Tony Zettl (with the assistance of Burt Garbow.)